# Can Create Hive Table using XML but having an error when Querying

Tags: hadoop, hive

I need to create a hive table using a set of xml files in a hadoop directory.

I have tried using the code below:

```
add jar hdfs:///user/hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test
(sport STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"column.xpath.sport"="/event_list/event/@Sport")
STORED AS 
INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION'/user/2019-04-21'
TBLPROPERTIES (
"xmlinput.start"="<event_list>",
"xmlinput.end"="</event_list>");
```

It returns the error below:
[image]

So I tried adding another jar file.

```
add jar hdfs:///user/hive_serde.jar;
```

and with this I can create the table.

Querying **select * from test limit 10;** will return a result but when querying with aggregates like **select sport, count(*) from test limit 10;** it returns an error below:

```
ERROR : Status: Failed
ERROR : Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1555929930390_0107_1_00, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1555929930390_0107_1_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:INIT_FAILURE, Fail to create InputInitializerManager, org.apache.tez.dag.api.TezReflectionException: Unable to instantiate class with 1 arguments: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator
        at org.apache.tez.common.ReflectionUtils.getNewInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:71)
        at org.apache.tez.common.ReflectionUtils.createClazzInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:89)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:152)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:148)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager.createInitializer(RootInputInitializerManager.java:148)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager.runInputInitializers(RootInputInitializerManager.java:121)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.setupInputInitializerManager(VertexImpl.java:4122)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.access$3100(VertexImpl.java:207)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl$InitTransition.handleInitEvent(VertexImpl.java:2932)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl$InitTransition.transition(VertexImpl.java:2879)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl$InitTransition.transition(VertexImpl.java:2861)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$MultipleInternalArc.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:385)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.access$500(StateMachineFactory.java:46)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$InternalStateMachine.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:487)
        at org.apache.tez.state.StateMachineTez.doTransition(StateMachineTez.java:59)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.handle(VertexImpl.java:1957)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.handle(VertexImpl.java:206)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster$VertexEventDispatcher.handle(DAGAppMaster.java:2317)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster$VertexEventDispatcher.handle(DAGAppMaster.java:2303)
        at org.apache.tez.common.AsyncDispatcher.dispatch(AsyncDispatcher.java:180)
        at org.apache.tez.common.AsyncDispatcher$1.run(AsyncDispatcher.java:115)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.tez.common.ReflectionUtils.getNewInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:68)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load plan: hdfs://sbx-hdp-mn01.ourbiworld.prod:8020/tmp/hive/hive/937f8627-235f-4adb-a06d-38a975990aaa/hive_2019-04-27_05-34-39_420_1560175914632249959-28/hive/_tez_scratch_dir/025ba737-1593-4ccc-b255-5959bc6d4b70/map.xml
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getBaseWork(Utilities.java:509)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getMapWork(Utilities.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator.<init>(HiveSplitGenerator.java:137)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create serializer "org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$EnumSerializer" for class: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.VirtualColumn
Serialization trace:
virtualCols (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.TableScanDesc)
conf (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator)
aliasToWork (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.MapWork)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:144)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:708)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObject(SerializationUtilities.java:218)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:790)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readClassAndObject(SerializationUtilities.java:180)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:161)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:39)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:708)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObject(SerializationUtilities.java:218)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:686)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObject(SerializationUtilities.java:210)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities.deserializeObjectByKryo(SerializationUtilities.java:707)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities.deserializePlan(SerializationUtilities.java:613)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities.deserializePlan(SerializationUtilities.java:590)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getBaseWork(Utilities.java:470)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create serializer "org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$EnumSerializer" for class: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.VirtualColumn
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.factories.ReflectionSerializerFactory.makeSerializer(ReflectionSerializerFactory.java:67)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.factories.ReflectionSerializerFactory.makeSerializer(ReflectionSerializerFactory.java:45)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.getDefaultSerializer(Kryo.java:359)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.registerImplicit(DefaultClassResolver.java:74)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.getRegistration(Kryo.java:490)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.getSerializer(Kryo.java:505)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:120)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:40)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:708)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObject(SerializationUtilities.java:218)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
        ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.factories.ReflectionSerializerFactory.makeSerializer(ReflectionSerializerFactory.java:60)
        ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: stringTypeInfo
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.VirtualColumn.<clinit>(VirtualColumn.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at java.lang.Class.getEnumConstantsShared(Class.java:3320)
        at java.lang.Class.getEnumConstants(Class.java:3297)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$EnumSerializer.<init>(DefaultSerializers.java:392)
        ... 66 more
]
ERROR : Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1555929930390_0107_1_01, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill in NEW state., Vertex vertex_1555929930390_0107_1_01 [Reducer 2] killed/failed due to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]
ERROR : DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:1
INFO  : org.apache.tez.common.counters.DAGCounter:
INFO  :    AM_CPU_MILLISECONDS: 500
INFO  :    AM_GC_TIME_MILLIS: 0
ERROR : FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1555929930390_0107_1_00, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1555929930390_0107_1_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:INIT_FAILURE, Fail to create InputInitializerManager, org.apache.tez.dag.api.TezReflectionException: Unable to instantiate class with 1 arguments: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator
        at org.apache.tez.common.ReflectionUtils.getNewInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:71)
        at org.apache.tez.common.ReflectionUtils.createClazzInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:89)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:152)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:148)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager.createInitializer(RootInputInitializerManager.java:148)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager.runInputInitializers(RootInputInitializerManager.java:121)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.setupInputInitializerManager(VertexImpl.java:4122)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.access$3100(VertexImpl.java:207)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl$InitTransition.handleInitEvent(VertexImpl.java:2932)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl$InitTransition.transition(VertexImpl.java:2879)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl$InitTransition.transition(VertexImpl.java:2861)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$MultipleInternalArc.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:385)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.access$500(StateMachineFactory.java:46)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$InternalStateMachine.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:487)
        at org.apache.tez.state.StateMachineTez.doTransition(StateMachineTez.java:59)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.handle(VertexImpl.java:1957)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.handle(VertexImpl.java:206)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster$VertexEventDispatcher.handle(DAGAppMaster.java:2317)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster$VertexEventDispatcher.handle(DAGAppMaster.java:2303)
        at org.apache.tez.common.AsyncDispatcher.dispatch(AsyncDispatcher.java:180)
        at org.apache.tez.common.AsyncDispatcher$1.run(AsyncDispatcher.java:115)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.tez.common.ReflectionUtils.getNewInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:68)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load plan: hdfs://sbx-hdp-mn01.ourbiworld.prod:8020/tmp/hive/hive/937f8627-235f-4adb-a06d-38a975990aaa/hive_2019-04-27_05-34-39_420_1560175914632249959-28/hive/_tez_scratch_dir/025ba737-1593-4ccc-b255-5959bc6d4b70/map.xml
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getBaseWork(Utilities.java:509)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getMapWork(Utilities.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator.<init>(HiveSplitGenerator.java:137)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create serializer "org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$EnumSerializer" for class: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.VirtualColumn
Serialization trace:
virtualCols (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.TableScanDesc)
conf (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator)
aliasToWork (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.MapWork)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:144)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:708)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObject(SerializationUtilities.java:218)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:790)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readClassAndObject(SerializationUtilities.java:180)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:161)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:39)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:708)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObject(SerializationUtilities.java:218)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:686)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObject(SerializationUtilities.java:210)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities.deserializeObjectByKryo(SerializationUtilities.java:707)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities.deserializePlan(SerializationUtilities.java:613)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities.deserializePlan(SerializationUtilities.java:590)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getBaseWork(Utilities.java:470)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create serializer "org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$EnumSerializer" for class: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.VirtualColumn
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.factories.ReflectionSerializerFactory.makeSerializer(ReflectionSerializerFactory.java:67)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.factories.ReflectionSerializerFactory.makeSerializer(ReflectionSerializerFactory.java:45)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.getDefaultSerializer(Kryo.java:359)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.registerImplicit(DefaultClassResolver.java:74)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.getRegistration(Kryo.java:490)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.getSerializer(Kryo.java:505)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:120)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:40)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:708)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObject(SerializationUtilities.java:218)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
        ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.factories.ReflectionSerializerFactory.makeSerializer(ReflectionSerializerFactory.java:60)
        ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: stringTypeInfo
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.VirtualColumn.<clinit>(VirtualColumn.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at java.lang.Class.getEnumConstantsShared(Class.java:3320)
        at java.lang.Class.getEnumConstants(Class.java:3297)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$EnumSerializer.<init>(DefaultSerializers.java:392)
        ... 66 more
]Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1555929930390_0107_1_01, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill in NEW state., Vertex vertex_1555929930390_0107_1_01 [Reducer 2] killed/failed due to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:1
INFO  : Completed executing command(queryId=hive_20190427053439_1914cb17-3ac9-43ce-9d1a-0fde3b0e117e); Time taken: 3.29 seconds
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1555929930390_0107_1_00, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1555929930390_0107_1_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:INIT_FAILURE, Fail to create InputInitializerManager, org.apache.tez.dag.api.TezReflectionException: Unable to instantiate class with 1 arguments: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator
        at org.apache.tez.common.ReflectionUtils.getNewInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:71)
        at org.apache.tez.common.ReflectionUtils.createClazzInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:89)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:152)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:148)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager.createInitializer(RootInputInitializerManager.java:148)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager.runInputInitializers(RootInputInitializerManager.java:121)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.setupInputInitializerManager(VertexImpl.java:4122)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.access$3100(VertexImpl.java:207)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl$InitTransition.handleInitEvent(VertexImpl.java:2932)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl$InitTransition.transition(VertexImpl.java:2879)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl$InitTransition.transition(VertexImpl.java:2861)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$MultipleInternalArc.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:385)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.access$500(StateMachineFactory.java:46)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$InternalStateMachine.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:487)
        at org.apache.tez.state.StateMachineTez.doTransition(StateMachineTez.java:59)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.handle(VertexImpl.java:1957)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.handle(VertexImpl.java:206)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster$VertexEventDispatcher.handle(DAGAppMaster.java:2317)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster$VertexEventDispatcher.handle(DAGAppMaster.java:2303)
        at org.apache.tez.common.AsyncDispatcher.dispatch(AsyncDispatcher.java:180)
        at org.apache.tez.common.AsyncDispatcher$1.run(AsyncDispatcher.java:115)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.tez.common.ReflectionUtils.getNewInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:68)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load plan: hdfs://sbx-hdp-mn01.ourbiworld.prod:8020/tmp/hive/hive/937f8627-235f-4adb-a06d-38a975990aaa/hive_2019-04-27_05-34-39_420_1560175914632249959-28/hive/_tez_scratch_dir/025ba737-1593-4ccc-b255-5959bc6d4b70/map.xml
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getBaseWork(Utilities.java:509)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getMapWork(Utilities.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator.<init>(HiveSplitGenerator.java:137)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create serializer "org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$EnumSerializer" for class: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.VirtualColumn
Serialization trace:
virtualCols (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.TableScanDesc)
conf (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator)
aliasToWork (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.MapWork)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:144)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:708)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObject(SerializationUtilities.java:218)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:790)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readClassAndObject(SerializationUtilities.java:180)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:161)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:39)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:708)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObject(SerializationUtilities.java:218)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:686)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObject(SerializationUtilities.java:210)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities.deserializeObjectByKryo(SerializationUtilities.java:707)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities.deserializePlan(SerializationUtilities.java:613)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities.deserializePlan(SerializationUtilities.java:590)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getBaseWork(Utilities.java:470)
        ... 32 more
```

The problem is I can create a table but cannot query.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your aggregation query does not contain `group by`, this is allowed only if you are aggregating all columns in the select. Add `group by sport`:

```
 select sport, count(*) cnt from test group by sport limit 10;
```